# Strange jQuery formatting, can anyone explain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dollar-sign

I've come across a plugin to toggle checkboxes (https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI/blob/master/js/flatui-checkbox.js).

However, it doesn't work properly with the latest version of jQuery so I'm having to debug it.

Can anyone explain the following?

```
if ($el.prop('disabled') == false) {
  $parent.toggleClass(ch) && checked ? $el.removeAttr(ch) : $el.attr(ch, true);
 $el.trigger(e).trigger('change'); 
}
```

Specifically, what is the deal with the `&&`? I know this is an AND operator, but I thought these only existed within `if` statements.

And also, what does the dollar in `$el` mean? It is set like this: `$el = $(element)`. I understand why it's needed on the right but don't know what point it serves on the left.

Comment: Oh right, so.. like a shorthand if?

Comment: Yes. Exactly [Ternary or Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: Putting a dollar sign in the variable name, like: `var $el = $(element)` is just a way of letting the programmer know that element is a jquery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, what is the deal with the &&? I know this is an AND operator, but I thought these only existed within if statements.

Yes it is a AND operand, and javascript is very *elastic* and *forgivable* in terms of using expressions.

> And also, what does the dollar in $el mean? It is set like this: $el = $(element). I understand why it's needed on the right but don't know what point it serves on the left.

This is just to indicate that the element retrieved with jQuery is stored inside the `$el` variable, it's only a matter of naming style, but not needed.

Basically this line is using the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator

```
$parent.toggleClass(ch) && checked ? $el.removeAttr(ch) : $el.attr(ch, true
```

but could be also written this way:

```
if($parent.toggleClass(ch) && checked){
   $el.removeAttr(ch);
} else {
   $el.attr(ch, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `&&` is written in a ternary operator. It is basically a shorthand `if(...){} else {}` statement. They are written as follows:

`[if statement] ? [if true, return this] ? [else, return this]`

[Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/conditionals-in-javascript/4/1) has a good tutorial on ternaries.

The `$el` is just the name of the variable for the `$(element)`. The `$` is not necessarily needed, and the variable could just as easily be named `el`. The leading `$` is sometimes included in the variable name for jQuery objects since it mimics jQuery's syntax of the leading `$`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression to the left of the `?` operator is just a boolean expression. `&&` can be used to construct any boolean expression as is the programmer doing here.

The puporse of `$el = (element);` is just to avoid doing `$(element)` all the time, which is not only longer to type, but it's calling `document.getElementById()` behind the scenes every time. The programmer is jut grabbing a reference to the object once. This is the same reason you would write:

```
var div = document.getElementById('somediv');
```

and continue using `div` down below...

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of explainations about the code, But the problem you are trying to solve is the fact [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) use changed after jQuery 1.6.

When you are setting the checked property of a checkbox, it should be using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`. And you should not use [`removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) for checked, you need to use `$el.prop(ch, false);`

```
$parent.toggleClass(ch) && checked ? $el.prop(ch, false); : $el.prop(ch, true);
```

or it can be written as

```
$el.prop(ch, !($parent.toggleClass(ch) && checked) );
```

Comment: Very interesting. Toggling using prop() makes no apparent changes to the markup (though visually the checks do behave correctly), whereas toggling using attr() actually adds `checked=true` (or false) to the markup. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes since you are not changing the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

this is just a ternary operator... shorthand for if condition

```
 $parent.toggleClass(ch) && checked ? $el.removeAttr(ch) : $el.attr(ch, true);
```

this means

```
if($parent.toggleClass(ch) && checked){
    $el.removeAttr(ch);
} else {
   $el.attr(ch, true);
}
```

and about $el..

it is just a variable name . i suppose there is another variable created that says

```
var $el=$(element);
```

this cache the jquery object for better performance and doest n't need to call getElementById() everytime it is mentioned

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case `&&` used to compile boolean var and run one of two statements, it's equals to:

```
if ($parent.toggleClass(ch) && checked)
   $el.removeAttr(ch);
else 
   $el.attr(ch, true);
```

Actually, I don't know language where `&&` is allowed only within `if` operator, but in JS you have even more freedom: you can use it as check condition "Need I to continue or not":

```
callback && callback(args);
```

will run only when `callback` is defined;

Finally, $ char in var name is just a mention that this var is jQuery wrapped object. It's not necessary.